# SQL vs NoSQL performance with large amounts of data

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

After many days of research and multiple load tests on my own servers and on AWS servers I decided to ask the community.

I am developing an image tracking platform. On this platform, users can follow images and other images that are sent as a reply to the ones that follow.

### Basic scheme

[image: Example schema]

The "tracking" table can reach 1,000,000,000 records in the next 12 months. We are concerned that for each user to visit our home will have to consult what are all the photos that follow and through them with a JOIN to collect the photos to show.
In the tracking table, DELETE and UPDATE are not made, only INSERTS.

I have performed tests generating dummy data with [Spawner Data Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spawner/) putting 100 million records in the "tracking" table. At the time of doing the three required JOIN I get a very good respio time (or so I think) of ~ 35ms but when I do 100 or more concurrent queries the system runs very slow even taking 25 seconds to answer.

I have come to think that MongoDB could help at least in the part that each user (document) has an array of ids of photos that follows (subdocument) but one of the problems is the limit of 16mb and another is to bring each "reply" (document with field photo_id). I have also tried to do a collection other than tracking (document with user_id and photo_id) to avoid the problem of 16mb but there is still the problem of bringing the "reply" (I do not think it is an optimal solution, besides I understand that for Relational data do not use NoSQL. You must use the appropriate tool)

### Questions:

1 - Is SQL designed to make such queries or am I making a bad use of technology?

2 - MongoDB should not be used in this case because it relies a lot on relational data. Am I right?

3 - Do you have any recommendations?

Honestly I am very concerned about performance, especially the condo reaches the billon of rows

[Why You Should Never Use MongoDB - Sarah Mei](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) : Article of interest that caused great stir for the title. I have read several opinions about that article and I am getting more confused

Servers Used for Testing:

First:

-AWS free tier with MariaDB.

Second:

-CPU: Celeron J1900

-RAM: 4GB 1666mhz

-SSD: 32 GB

-OS: Ubuntu server 16.04

-Software: MariaDB

Third:

-CPU: i7 7700

-RAM: 16GB 2133mhz

-SSD: 512

-OS: Windows 10

-Software: MariaDB

Comment: Please read this, especially the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Also, if you want to get your service to a billion rows of data, you need to get it to a million first. Concentrate on that. When you start getting a lot of traffic, you can start worrying about sharding, caching, replicating, and all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is SQL designed to make such queries...?

Queries like what? You haven't shown any queries.

When you need to optimize queries against millions of rows, you have to be very specific about *which* queries you're optimizing. You can use indexing or partitioning or other techniques, but every kind of optimization optimizes for specific queries *at the expense of other queries.*

> MongoDB should not be used in this case because it relies a lot on relational data. Am I right?

MongoDB 3.2 supports `$lookup` which is kind of like an outer join. But it's unlikely to be as efficient as an indexed join in SQL.

Another strategy for MongoDB would be to store more complex documents, with all the dependent data together in nested structures. That way you don't have to do joins, but it optimizes for a certain kind of data retrieval.

> Do you have any recommendations?

I would recommend sizing your servers properly to the volume of data you will be working with.

- Give them enough RAM so you can hold the dataset in the InnoDB buffer pool. Make sure to tune your MySQL/MariaDB options to take advantage of the system RAM.
- Give them more powerful CPUs that can execute more concurrent threads (the top  CPU in your case is still a single 4-core CPU with HT for only 8 threads). It's no surprise that your modest CPU gets overwhelmed by 100 concurrent threads.

Also plan to use cache more. Queries against large datasets will be expensive. The quickest query possible is one that you don't have to execute at all, because the result is already in cache. You need to architect at the application level to reduce SQL query load.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry I did not give the necessary details. When I asked if SQL was designed for this I was referring mainly to the multiple entries in the "tracking" table. You have my doubts and I will try to optimize the "tracking" table in addition to implementing cache with Redis

Comment: @LordSuricato, I see you removed the accepted answer from my answer. You might consider adding a bounty to your question if you want to get more attention or answers from other people. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers